# issues with css a:link tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added CSS to create an underline when the user hovers. 
The links are Javascript commands to submit a form.

The issue I'm having is:
*if you scroll on one it triggers the other link, both, or neither.*

Here is the CSS:

```
a:link {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
text-underline-position: under;
text-decoration-color:  #ff0000;
}

a:active {
color: #ff0000;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td style="width: 40px;">
     <input type="submit" value="" tabindex="11" class="btnSubmit" formvalidate>
  </td>
  <td style="width: 350px;">
     <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
       <a href="javascript.void(0);" onclick="validateForm();">SUBMIT</a>
     </div>
  </td>
  <td width="5%">
     <input type="reset" value="" tabindex="12" class="btnReset">
  </td>
  <td>
     <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
       <a href="" onclick="booking.reset();">RESET</a>
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And the JS (if you think the function might be the culprit):

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["booking"]["Email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("E-mail must be filled out.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Do you really need a reset button?](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the text-underline-position and it works perfectly. My guess is, your browser probably doesn't support text-underline-position. Heres the link to MDN so you can read more about what it does and browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. I also switched the text-decoration for a border to come on instead. This is working much better. Thanks!